Congruences of partition function
I'm trying to understand Ken Ono's results showing Erdös' conjecture for the primes $\ge5$. He first shows the following: let $m\ge5$ be prime and let $k>0$. A positive proportion of the primes $\ell$ have the property that$$p\left(\frac{m^k\ell^3n+1}{24}\right)\equiv0\mod m$$for every $n\ge0$ coprime to $\ell$, where $p$ denotes the partition function. Why does it follows from it that$$\{n\le X:p(n)\equiv0\mod m\}\gg_m X$$if $m\ge5$? The first result should mean that $$\underset{\ell \le X}{\sum_{\ell\tiny\mbox{prime with above property}}}1\sim\alpha\frac{X}{\log X},$$for some $\alpha>0$.
